# Confusion about a simple python wsgi server (wsgiref.simple_server)

Tags: python, network-programming, shared-libraries, wsgi

This is a simple python wsgi server that prints out `Hello guys!!!` on `0.0.0.0:8080`.

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

content = 'Hello guys!!!'

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return [content]

server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, application)
server.serve_forever()
```

Several questions arise when looking at this code:

1. How can the `make_server` function work with just the function name `application`?
   I don't see how this does anything else then return the `"<function application at 0x7f71686286e0>"` string (`application.__repr__() method` of function object).
2. Why does the application function definition define `environ` as an argument when it isn't used inside this function and isn't even set in an `application` function call later on?
3. From what I understand the `start_response` argument in the function definition is used here as a sort of identifier that this will be the name of the function that sets other properties later needed in the `make_server` function call. Where is that functionality defined in the standard library? (I have checked the source of the relevant modules but I don't understand where this it is done exactly)

Observations: Changing the argument `environ` in the function definition does not change anything in the behaviour of the code, the `start_response` argument however has to have the same name as `start_response` in the body of the `application` function.

I know `os.environ` is a dictionary but I can't find where it is called in the python standard library. If the `environ` argument is necessary and the only viable first argument, I don't understand why they would require you to explicitly name a first argument(`environ`) every time, it gives you the illusion that using a different argument affects its behaviour. I am aware of the "better explicit then implicit"-python policy but here I think it is useless and confusing.

### Edit

Because of Ned's answer I now understand by looking at the source that `make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, application)` creates an instance of `WSGIServer` such as `wsgiref.simple_server.WSGIServer((host, port), handler_class))`. Looking deeper I found that the initialisation method is inherited from `BaseServer` . BaseServer instances have `server_address` and  `RequestHandlerClass` as instance variables among others.
The function object `application` is stored in the `application` class variable of `WSGIServer`.

But I still can't find where else this `application` class variable is used somewhere in the python source. (I 've searched through all modules that contain class definitions of parent classes of `WSGIServer`) Does anybody know where it is used? Finding that could potentially answer all my questions.

Answer (score 3):

The important Python concept here is that functions are objects like anything else, and can be assigned to variables:

```
>>> def double(x):
...     return 2*x
...

>>> my_fn = double
>>> my_fn(4)
8
```

When you use the name of a function without parens, you are simply talking about the function, not invoking it.

In this line:

```
server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, application)
```

`application` is a function, and you are passing it as a value to `make_server`, which will later be able to invoke it.  That's how your application is called.  One of the values passed into your `application` function is yet another function, called `start_response`.  This is a function written by the WSGI authors, and they give it to you to invoke, which you do with the line

```
start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
```

Your `application` function has to take two arguments, conventionally called environ and start_response.  You don't use the environ value, but more complex WSGI apps will.  The WSGI framework expects all application functions to take two arguments, so it always invokes the function with two arguments, so you have to define yours with two arguments, or it won't work properly.

Comment: Thanks Ned. This helps a lot but still does not explains everything. See my `Edit` in the original post.